# Can you run a report to see how many dashboards a user is running?

Tags: reporting, dashboard, admin

We have had an admin leave and want to make sure there are no dashboards they are the 'Running User' for. Is there a way to run a report or see how many dashboards someone is a running user for?

Comment: Probably the easiest way would be to download the dashboards with [sfdx](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/sfdxcli), since you presumably want to be able to mass update any dashboards that (may still be/are) running as that user.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new Custom Report Type under Settings. The Primary Object is Dashboards. The Secondary Object is Dashboard Components. Save this Custom Report Type.
Now create a new report with this report type.  Add a filter to the report with 'Running User' equals 'enter name of your admin'. Also change the filters Show Me to 'All Dashboards' and Created Date to 'All Time'.

Comment: This worked, thanks so much